# Use configure file to generate makefile

Tags: c++, c, linux, gcc, g++

I use ./configure command to generate a makefile. My compiler is arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi toochain. When I ran ./configure, I got the following problem:

> tl@tl-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/mvux_camera/demo/sampli_save_demo$ ./configure --host=/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++
>   configure: WARNING: if you wanted to set the --build type, don't use --host.
>       If a cross compiler is detected then cross compile mode will be used
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
>   checking whether build environment is sane... yes
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-strip... no
>   checking for strip... strip
>   checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for mawk... mawk
>   checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-g++... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-c++... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-gpp... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-aCC... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-CC... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-cxx... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-cc++... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-cl.exe... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-FCC... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-KCC... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-RCC... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-xlC_r... no
>   checking for /home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-xlC... no
>   checking for g++... no
>   checking for c++... no
>   checking for gpp... no
>   checking for aCC... no
>   checking for CC... no
>   checking for cxx... no
>   checking for cc++... no
>   checking for cl.exe... no
>   checking for FCC... no
>   checking for KCC... no
>   checking for RCC... no
>   checking for xlC_r... no
>   checking for xlC... no
>   checking whether the C++ compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in '/home/tl/Desktop/mvux_camera/demo/sampli_save_demo':
>   configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables
>   See 'config.log' for more details

My toolchain was sourced, when typing `arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v`, the command line shows it works.

> tl@tl-virtual-machine:~/Desktop/mvux_camera/demo/sampli_save_demo$ arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v
>   Using built-in specs.
>   COLLECT_GCC=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc
>   COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/../libexec/gcc/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/4.6.2/lto-wrapper
>   Target: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi
>   Configured with: /work/build/.build/src/gcc-linaro-4.6-2011.06-0/configure --build=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --host=i686-build_pc-linux-gnu --target=arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13 --with-sysroot=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --enable-languages=c,c++ --with-pkgversion='Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2011/08/10 09:20' --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libmudflap --disable-libgomp --disable-libssp --with-gmp=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpfr=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-mpc=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-ppl=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-cloog=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-libelf=/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static --with-host-libstdcxx='-static-libgcc -Wl,-Bstatic,-lstdc++,-Bdynamic -lm -L/work/build/.build/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/build/static/lib -lpwl' --enable-threads=posix --enable-target-optspace --enable-plugin --enable-multilib --with-local-prefix=/work/fsl-linaro-toolchain-2.13/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/multi-libs --disable-nls --enable-c99 --enable-long-long --with-system-zlib
>   Thread model: posix
>   gcc version 4.6.2 20110630 (prerelease) (Freescale MAD -- Linaro 2011.07 -- Built at 2011/08/10 09:20)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output of `./configure --help`, especially:

```
System types:
  --build=BUILD     configure for building on BUILD [guessed]
  --host=HOST       cross-compile to build programs to run on HOST [BUILD]
```

`HOST` should be the identity of the system on which you want your cross-compiled
program to run. But you have set it to the absolute filename of your C++ compiler:

```
./configure --host=/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++
```

which results in your `./configure` script attempting and failing to locate a cross-compiler
with such nonsense names as:

```
/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-g++
/home/tl/Desktop/opt/Embedsky/gcc-4.6.2-glibc-2.13-linaro-multilib-2011.12/tq-linaro-toolchain/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++-c++
```

Look at the output of `arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc -v`, specifically:

```
Target: arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi
```

This tells you that your cross-compiler was built to cross-compile programs
for `arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi` systems. Therefore, when you want to `./configure`
a project to use that cross-compiler, `HOST` = `arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi`

Comment: Hello,Mr Kinghan.
I followed your advice,and it works.Thanks very much.

Comment: @Light Hi, and welcome to Stackoverflow. Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)